# Разделитель ячеек PickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Не могу скрыть разделитель ячеек PickerView
(строка под текстом)

[image: Граница ячеек]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Красивое решение вряд ли найдете, поскольку в iOS7 и позже `showsSelectionIndicator` больше не работает.

Некрасивое вот такое:

В методе `titleForRow` либо `viewForRow` в делегате написать

```
[[pickerview.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:YES];
[[pickerview.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:YES];
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612279/ios7-uipickerview-how-to-hide-the-selection-indicator).

Comment: спасибо, помогло